# Passing Password to zfs mount command

Tags: mount, password, encryption, zfs

I have four encrypted zfs datasets that I need to mount by hand at the boot of my development machine using the command `zfs mount -l -a`. These datasets all have the same password and I have to type it in four times.

Is there a way to streamline this in a secure way so I only have to type the password once? Maybe there is a secure way to have the password automatically entered?

Answer (score 2):

If datasets have the same password, yet you need to enter it multiple times, this should mean that said datasets use different encryption roots/key locations; the output of `zfs get encryptionroot,keylocation <pool>/<dataset1> <pool>/<dataset2> [...]` should confirm this. You can use `zfs change-key` (see `man zfs-change-key`) to unify this.

To have the password entered automatically at boot time, you could use *Network-Bound Disk Encryption (NBDE)*. Ubuntu provides packages for both [Clevis](https://github.com/latchset/clevis) and [Tang](https://github.com/latchset/tang), but you'd need to provide your own auxiliary script (e.g., in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-premount/`) in order to ensure that the required keys are loaded. (Of course, Clevis–a pluggable framework for automated decryption–can work without Tang as well.)

Answer (score 0):

For automated entry of password encrypted datasets, it can be automated using `/etc/rc.local` by adding the following template script:

```
_ZKY_=$(echo <base64_enc_pass> | base64 --decode)
echo $_ZKY_ | zfs mount -l <ds_1>
echo $_ZKY_ | zfs mount -l <ds_2>
...
```

Where:

- base64_enc_pass: Your password encrypted base64. You can enter the plaintext password if that is your poison.
- ds_n: Dataset name(s) to decrypt and mount

Note: to enable `rc.local` on `systemd` enabled systems, here are [some instructions](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-enable-etcrc-local-with-systemd).

Alternatively, if you want to do this on demand, use this python script to streamline the entry of password just once:

Source for zmount.py:

```
import getpass
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
_p=getpass.getpass('ZFS Dataset Password:')
for _ds in sys.argv[1:]:
    p = Popen(['zfs', 'mount', '-l', _ds], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    _ = p.communicate(input=_p.encode())[0]
```

To use zmount.py:

```
% python3 zmount.py <ds_1> <ds_2>[ ...]
```